# A warning message invalid argument in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Someone please help me. I'm new to `codeigniter`. I'm getting the errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Warning  Message: Missing argument 1 for Detail_organize_cont::viewOrganize()  Filename: reader/detail_organize_cont.php  Line Number: 53 

A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined variable: id  Filename: reader/detail_organize_cont.php  Line Number: 72
```

**My controller :**

```
 function viewOrganize($id)
 {
    // Redirect unauthenticated users to signin page
    if ( ! $this->authentication->is_signed_in())
    {
        redirect('account/sign_in');
    }

    // Retrieve sign in user
    $data['account'] = $this->account_model->get_by_id($this->session->userdata('account_id'));
    // No access to users without a password
    if ( ! $data['account']->password) redirect('');


    // Enable SSL?
    $data['account'] = $this->account_model->get_by_id($this->session->userdata('account_id'));
    $data['account_details'] = $this->account_details_model->get_by_account_id($this->session->userdata('account_id'));

    $row=$this->detail_organize_model->getID($id);
    $data['organization']=$row;
    $this->load->view('reader/detail_organize_view',  $data );
```

**My Model:**

```
function get_by_id($account_id)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('tb_admin', array('id' => $account_id))->row();
}


function getID($id){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('tb_organize');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query=$this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;
}
```

**My Views**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="org" placeholder="Organization" value="<? echo $organization->id;?>" disabled>
```

Please help me.Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is your `function viewOrganize($id)` called ?

Comment: the errors appear self explanatory. what code is on files and lines they indicate?

Answer (score 3):

You really do need to read the Error messages as these two are being very explicit as to what your issue is.

You have a method in your controller ie

```
function viewOrganize($id){
  // stuff in here
}
```

You have defined it as having a parameter called $id that you must provide and you are Calling it Without providing $id to it.

Which is Exactly what the error message...

> A PHP Error was encountered  Severity: Warning  Message: Missing
>   argument 1 for Detail_organize_cont::viewOrganize()  Filename:
>   reader/detail_organize_cont.php  Line Number: 53

Is screaming out very loudly and wildly waving it's arms about ( If it could ).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you calling this method by uri like this: `Detail_organize_cont/viewOrganize/{ID}`. Error that you mentioned means that variable `$id` was never set.
Try to add route to your `application/config/route.php` file like this:

```
$route['Detail_organize_cont/viewOrganize/(:num)'] = 'Detail_organize_cont/viewOrganize/$1';
```

More over you should alway set default value to `$id` (like `$id = NULL`) and check in method if parameter was set. CodeIgniter routing is very poor and... Better check your parameters ;)

Good Luck!